# HQL запрос с map в Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, map, hql

Как создать запрос `HQL` в `Java` вида:

```
`select new map(A.a1, B.b1) from A left join B on A.a2=B.b2`
```

Где `B` может не существовать? Сейчас возвращает результат только когда `B` существует.

Comment: Покажите классы сущностей и код, в котором вы осуществляете запрос. Я не смог повторить вашу проблему, без проблем получил отображения, содержащие null.

Comment: Все норм. Извините, неправильно составил запрос - было еще условие "where B.b3 = smth". Спасибо )